# NSUserDefaults not Storing the data. It Stores Nill Value Instead

Tags: ios, swift, nsuserdefaults

NSUser defaults wont store my data
i wrote the code in Playground to check the problem and the I got Nill value.. Xcode 7.2
kindly check that whats wrong in the code        [Image enclosed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zdlFG.png)

Comment: Abdul Waheed please post code, not images of code. The '{}' button is exactly for the purpose of posting code, thanks!

Comment: saving `NSUserdefaults` works asynchronously. You'll get unreliable results when reading it back instantly.

Comment: Not sure if it was just an example or not but `NSUserDefaults` is **not** a secure place to store a users password. Especially in plain text. If you want to store the password, look at using the Keychain. Also `NSUserDefaults` wont work in a playground so test your code in a real project.

Comment: `UserDefaults` does NOT work in playgrounds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the `NSUserDefaults` does not work properly in Xcode Playground 7.2.

The following code

```
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject("hello world", forKey: "key1")

NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("key1")
```

does return `nil` in Xcode Playground 7.2.

However the same code executed on a real project (and executed into the simulator) does work and the second line does return `hello world`.

Answer (score 0):

Hi replace the following code in real project, as `NSUserDefaults` returns `nil` in `Playground`. `NSUserDefaults` won't work in a playground so try your code in a real project

**Complete code sample:**

```
import UIKit

let userdefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
var name = "myname"
var pass = "123"

userdefaults.setValue(name, forKey: "username")
userdefaults.setValue(pass, forKey: "userpass")


print(userdefaults.valueForKey("username"))
```

The last line will return value for key `username`.

Comment: He is using Xcode 7.2 which means Swift 2.1. Your code is not for Swift 2.1 (`println` no longer exists). I tested your code in Xcode Playground 7.2 and it does not compile. I fixed the compile error and the problem described in the OP is still there, infact `userdefaults.valueForKey("username")` does return `nil`.

Comment: This is the result in my Xcode Playground 7.2 `fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`. What does happen on your Xcode Playground? On my side `NSUserDefaults` is not finding the previously saved value. I think it's a bug in Xcode Playground 7.2

Comment: If the retrieved value is `nil` then this `print(userdefaults.valueForKey("username")!)` line **must** produce an error because you are force unwrapping a `nil` value. To get the result you are talking about you must remove this `!` character.

Comment: Yes. I have already removed that form playground but forgot to remove form here. thank for identifying.

Comment: Perfect :) Now you can see that `NSUserDefaults` is not retrieving the previous saved value. The same problem the OP was talking about.

Comment: Don't use `valueForKey: / setValue:forKey:`. It's a KVC method with special functionality. It's inappropriate to be used with `NSUserDefaults`. There are specific methods `stringForKey: / setString:forKey:` to handle strings.

Answer (score 0):

Tested with Xcode 7.1.1 & Swift 2

- NSUserDefaults does not work properly -> looks like a bug or limitation of Playgrounds
- NSKeyedArchiver does work properly